# What is the meaning that dark count rate (DCR) is $\rm 1M/s$?

Tags: optics, photons

The dark count rate (DCR) is defined as pulses per second in dark condition, that is, the count rate that is measured in the absence of photons. The false detection events are mostly of thermal origin and can therefore be strongly suppressed by using a cooled type of detector. The dark-count rate (DCR) is a key parameter of single-photon detectors.

And I want to know, how to understand the dark count approximate $10^3$ cps, and the count rate is not more than 1M/s? But in someplace, I see the dark count rate can be 0-40 GHz. I don't understand the unit of them.

Comment: Can you tell us what kind of detector you're referring to and where you got the numbers?

Comment: OK, using the (InGaAs／InP) avalanche photodiode single photon detector,  the dark count approximate $10^{3}$ cps, and the count rate is not more than 1M/s, this is from a Chinese paper in the year of 2007. And $0-40$ GHz is from https://arxiv.org/pdf/2003.02765.pdf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The paper is pretty murky. Hz is the same unit as cps. The 40 GHz of that paper appears to be the dark current (in electrons/second) of a heavily radiation-damaged detector. I think the "count rate" is the rate of real photon detections, not dark current.

Comment: I don't understand the relationship between $10^3$ cps and $1M/s$, I though they all represent the dark count first, but clearly, I was wrong,